# MySQL #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: php, html, mysql

I got problem on my table 2. I dont know what is the error all about, because it's not so specific. I've tried to google it, but wont work.

## table 1

```
create table city(
city_id serial primary key,
city varchar(255),
province_id int,
foreign key(province_id) references province(province_id)
);
```

## table 2

```
create table baranggay(
baranggay_id serial primary key,
baranggay varchar(255),
city_id int,
foreign key(city_id) references city(city_id)
);
```

Comment: You have a type mismatch between `city_id int` and `city_id serial`. They must be exactly the same type, so you will need to make the referencing table use `BIGINT UNSIGNED` (which is what `SERIAL` means)

Comment: i have 3 tables actually : province, city, and baranggay

Comment: Changing the type to match will allow the tables to create successfully http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1603 (removed the FK from `city` for demonstration without its referenced table)

Comment: omg that works, Thanks Michael, I don't know how to vote your reply.

Comment: You need not vote it. I linked this question to an existing one explaining the reasons for the 1215 error in detail.

Comment: yea there are lots of 1215 error, but different situation. Thanks again mate.